# I can't get texcount to count words from my input files

Tags: chapters, overleaf, input, include, texcount

I am trying to use texcount to count the number of words in my document which is set-up in a way similar to this:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{Latex_writing/Chapters/Introduction.tex}

\chapter{History}
\input{Latex_writing/Chapters/History.tex}

\chapter{Literature review}
\input{Latex_writing/Chapters/litreview.tex}
```

I am using the following code to produce a separate document with the number of words:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{report} 

\usepackage{verbatim}


\newcommand{\detailtexcount}[1]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount Workingfile.tex -merge -total  -q #1.tex output.bbl > #1.wcdetail }%
  \verbatiminput{#1.wcdetail}%
}

\newcommand{\quickwordcount}[1]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount Workingfile.tex -1 -merge -sum -q #1.tex output.bbl > #1-words.sum }%
  \input{#1-words.sum} words%
}

\newcommand{\quickcharcount}[1]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount  Workingfile.tex -1 -merge -sum  -char -q #1.tex output.bbl > #1-chars.sum }%
  \input{#1-chars.sum} characters (not including spaces)%
}


\begin{document} 

\quickwordcount{Workingfile}
\quickcharcount{Workingfile}
\detailtexcount{Workingfile}

\end{document}
```

The problem I am having is that it doesn't seem to add the number of words in each file that I have input in my document.
I have tried workarounds such as changing from -merge to -inc, but that doesn't work.

Here is an example of the output:

[image]

How can I get texcount to include the number of words in each input file.
NB: I am working with latex on overleaf

Comment: Can you get the verbose output and see what the 29 error messages are? Could it be that there are 29 \input calls? An immediate idea is that it could be the path to the chapters that are causing the problem. If you include \input{path to chapter} in the counting document, does it find the chapter file? If this is the problem, you might need to specify the -dir or -dir= options: default is -dir=. which means paths are relative to the current working directory, while option -dir mean relative to the main document. I'm not familiar with using Overleaf, so don't know how files are organised there.

Comment: I have tried with -dir but that did not change anything. I tried -dir=Latex_writing/Chapters/ and -dir="Latex_writing/Chapters/". But both didn't change anything. I will add the complete log that I have to see if there is a way to fix the problem.

Comment: If you drop the -q option, error messages should be included, but I suspect they will just say the file could not be found. Btw, the arguments to texcount includes the document twice, once as Workingfile.tex and once as #1.tex, and thus it is counted twice as may be seen in the summary. Also the file output.bbl does not seem to be found. I'm suspecting there may be something about how Overleaf locates files that causes problems. Instead of running texcount, you could try running something like `ls -r` to list the directory content, and hopefulle provide some clue.